# I can't get http code 404 with libcurl

Tags: c++, libcurl

When I send a http request using a wrong server address like 127.0.0.1 as the server address of a URL, the libcurl returns CURLE_OK and get me the http code 0. However, I get http code 404 when I send the same request with IE. Does anyone know how can I get an error code rather than 0 with libcurl when sending request like that.

Comment: IE is not a protocol validation tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

libcurl returns CURLE_OK when the transfer went fine. Getting a 404 from a HTTP server is considered a fine transfer. You can make >=4xx HTTP response codes cause a libcurl error by setting the [CURLOPT_FAILONERROR](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTFAILONERROR) option.

Alternatively, and this may be the nicer way, you extract the HTTP response code after the transfer, with for example [curl_easy_getinfo()](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html) to figure out the HTTP response code to see what the HTTP server thought about the resource you requested.

Comment: Thank you author of curl. Does liburl consider it's a fine transfer when I send a request using POST to a site that doesn't have a web server?

Comment: If you do that, it won't return CURLE_OK.

Comment: Problem resolved. It turns out my 80 port is being used by Skype. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try using it to visit a site that's actually running a web server, and try to retrieve a file that doesn't exist. For example, http://www.google.com/404. Your browser is almost certainly not actually getting a 404 from visiting 127.0.0.1, even if it's telling you that's what it got.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But how do I know if a site is actually running a web server using libcurl?

Comment: I don't think I understand. The web server doesn't run libcurl. Your client uses libcurl, and you can use it to query any web server on the net.

Comment: If you want to know how you can tell whether libcurl was unable to retrieve a file because of a 404 or because it couldn't contact the server at all, you should use the response code from your libcurl request. e.g. see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_strerror.html

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't make it clear. My point is that my libcurl request returns CURLE_OK when I set the server to 127.0.0.1 so that I can't know that the request has failed.

Comment: @ncubrian That is probably you have a http server on your localhost. You can try `curl 127.0.0.1` to see if it shows web page html.

Comment: I tried curl -i 127.0.0.1 and it shows HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found

Comment: I also tried curl -vX POST 127.0.0.1 and it shows garbled characters. Is this a bug in libcurl?